# radio buttons to select the right answer, and save it to a new activity

Tags: android, eclipse, radio-button, save, image

i want to create on eclipse (android) some sort of a game within an app i am currently developing and it will show a picture and some radio buttons and in order to continue the user must select the right one and the app will sent the data to another activity as result for the user, attempts how many time. any suggestions on how to do it? codewise. Thank you

Comment: Codewise: `RadioGroup`, `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, `Intent`

Comment: @MocialovBoris don't forget an `ImageView` and some logic ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mybringback.com/series/android-intermediate/

Watch the first 4 videos in this series. They show you exactly how to do this.